# How to revert commit in github and restore files in VS code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-commit

So I was a beginner to github and how commits and all works. Long story short I thought I deleted every file in my project but now there are "changes" in the source control. I'm not too sure what to do and how to get my original project back. [This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R9wc.png)

I really need help and I'm really desperate. I thought to discard changes but the message that says all files will be permanently deleted is very very daunting.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you run `git status`? That's usually the best way to find out the current state of your repository.

If the problem is as simple as having just deleted all of your files, then that should be an easy fix. You can run `git reset --hard HEAD` and that will reset you to your most recent commit. That should restore anything you've deleted since the last commit. You'll lose any work that you've done since the last time you committed (but if the files have indeed been deleted, then presumably you've already lost that work).

If you want to go back further and actually erase the last commit, then you can use `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. If you keep doing that, you'll keep stepping back through commits and removing them from the branch. Be careful, only remove the commits that you want to use.

Use `git log` to see the commit history, so that you know where you are and you know what commits you're removing. Don't remove anything unless you're sure you want to. By default, `git log` tries to show you the entire commit history, which can be far too much information. I like using `git log --oneline -n5`, which shows you the last 5 commits, in a condensed one-line form.

(Important question: are the files actually missing? can you see them in a file browser?)

I've only ever used Git through the command line, so I'm not familiar with the visual studio interface. That means I can't advise about the 'changes' column on the left.

I am very confused about the error message that you're getting though "not a valid object name: HEAD". That seems strange. HEAD should always be valid; It just means "whatever commit is currently checked out".

I'm sorry I couldn't be more help. But posting the results of "git status" might be useful.

(Is your project backed up anywhere btw? Such as Gitlab or Github? If so, then sometimes it's easiest just to wipe your whole local directory and the restore it from the remote server.)

Comment: The files were actually missing in the file browser so I started panicking and I think I just deleted my whole project. But thank you so much for your help and sorry for wasting my time. This will be a really good reference later on. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to reset HEAD for your local repository.

you can use Git reset command.

`git reset`

If you want you can learn more about [Git HEAD](https://acompiler.com/git-head/)